# jQuery - How to animate scroll to element and add 100px in top

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code that i use to animate scroll to specific element.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#establishment3").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

**Question:**
How can i animate the scroll to this element but to scroll in 100px from top of the element ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#establishment3").offset().top - 100
}, 2000);
```

> *scroll in 100px from top of the element*

I don't understand whether you wanna go below or above. Give a `+ 100` if you wanna go below, or `- 100` if you wanna go `100px` above the element.